# OpenVPN MULTI: bad source address from client [192.168.0.x], packet dropped

Tags: debian, openvpn, configuration

I have a problem with the openVPN server (Debian 10), I know this question has already been asked, but nothing helped me.

I connect to my openVPN server on the local network, everything works fine, but SOMETIMES I get this message from the openVPN server:

`MULTI: bad source address from client [192.168.0.x], packet dropped`

When such a message is received, nothing happens, the connection to the server remains, only some packets are dropped.

`192.168.0.x` - This is the ip address of my local device from which I connect (android).

I am using an `.ovpn` file to connect to openVPN.
And now I want to ask, since this message only appears occasionally, should I be worried about this? Can this be somehow solved?

`server.conf`:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway autolocal"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
max-clients 2
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
satus /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

`client.ovpn`:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.0.x 1194 
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
verb 3

#CERTIFICATES...
```

In `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Sorry for my English, and thanks in advance :) !!!